# Selected value not passed in Django

Tags: html, django

I want to pass the selected values to have dependent dropdown with data connection. I am using `<select>` in HTML to pass value to Django but selected values can't be passed in Python for processing.

I am new to Django and prefer not to use `models.py` or `forms.py` at the moment.

```
<select class="Lv0" name="lv0">
  <option value="US">US</option>
  <option value="UK">UK</option>
</select>
```

`views.py`

```
def search_index(request):
    results = []
    lv0=""
    search_term = ""
    if request.GET.get('lv0'):
        lv0 = request.GET['lv0']
    print(lv0)                        //this can't be printed
    if request.GET.get('query'):
        search_term = request.GET['query']
    print("####test#####\n", search_term)   //this is printed
    results = esearch(query=search_term)
    print(results)                         //this is printed
    context = {'results': results, 'count': len(results), 'search_term': search_term}
    return render(request, 'esearch/base.html', context)
```

Below is for `query` that gets passed.

```
  <form class="form-inline">
    <input 
    class="form-control mr-sm-2" 
    type="query" placeholder="Search Here" 
    aria-label="query"
    name = 'query'
    value = "">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: The <select>  isn't included in the form?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I included that in the form and the value get passed. Thank you! It seems I have to press a button for the value to get passed. Is there a way to pass the value without hitting a button? I would like to have a dependent dropdown filled given the selected value. Thanks.

Comment: If you press a button of type="submit", then the browser knows it has to submit the form. You can also do it in Javascript in many other ways, but that's a bit far away from the question.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't had a chance to go through your code thoroughly and test it on my machine, but at least one thing is missing. Select is not attached to your form, so it would not submit when someone clicked the Search button.

Edit your form to have an ID and attach that ID to your `<select>` using `form="myform"`

**Full example:**

Your `<form>` HTML

```
<form class="form-inline" id="myform">
    <input 
    class="form-control mr-sm-2" 
    type="query" placeholder="Search Here" 
    aria-label="query"
    name = 'query'
    value = "">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
  </form>
```

Your `<select>`

```
<select class="Lv0" name="lv0" form="myform">
  <option value="US">US</option>
  <option value="UK">UK</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to pass the value without hitting a button (maybe not using select) ?  I would like to have a dependent dropdown filled given the selected value. Thanks

Comment: You would use something like that which is found in this tutorial.https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html I have used it several times to do a dependent dropdown.

Comment: Thanks. I have read that multiple times as well. Unfortunately still not able to quite get it as I am not sure how to use `models.py` or `views.py` with elasticsearch as data source. I posted an earlier question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58075671/django-select2-chained-dropdown-with-elasticsearch .Now I am trying using JQuery Select2 with Ajax without `models.py` or `views.py`. Looking forward to any advice.